# javascript datepicker not activating

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

My problem is that my datepicker does not work when I create my input field through javascript.

I have a button which will generate the fields needed for the input. One of these is a datepicker. I have a function which brings up a small calendar for the user to pick from. It works for input fields that aren't created by the javascript function.

this is the javascript function to create an input field:

```
<script lang="javascript">
    TestNo = 1; // This is input files added by default.
    TestMax = 50;
    TestMin = 1;

    function Test_Addchild() {
        if (TestNo <= TestMax) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id = 'divfiles' + TestNo;
            //div.style.width = "100px";
            //div.style.height = "100px";
            //div.style.background = "red";
            //div.style.color = "white";
            div.innerHTML = '<input size="35" type="text" id="Test' + TestNo + 'D" name="Test' + TestNo + 'D" value="Date ' + TestNo + '" class="form-control selector" autocomplete="off">';
            document.getElementById('Tests').appendChild(div);

            TestNo++;
            $('#<%= NoOfTests.ClientID %>').val(TestNo-1);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('Maximum ' + TestMax + ' Files are Allowed.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    function Test_Delchild() {
        if (TestNo > TestMin) {
            cnt = TestNo - 1;
            element = document.getElementById('divfiles' + cnt);
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            TestNo--;
            $('#<%= NoOfTests.ClientID %>').val(TestNo-1);
            return false;

        }
        else {
            alert('All tests removed');
            return false;
        }
    }        
</script>
```

These are the buttons creating and deleting the input field:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="Test_Addchild()">Add more tests</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="Test_Delchild()">Remove tests</a><br>
```

And lastly the datepicker function

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".selector").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I get the datepicker function to work for dynamically created input fields?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are facing this issue because your function for `datepicker` activation is working before the one which is adding fields.

Comment: Try delegating the handler to the body instead of the selector directly. The docs should have the correct syntax.

Comment: Try changing your type="text" to type="date". That should make the control a datepicker.